# Execution plan cost estimation

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

There is a problem in which i have to update a table with millions of record based on certain conditions.I have written a long shell script and SQL statements to do it.To check the performance , i plan on using explain plan ,studying it from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm#19259

Here it is written that "Execution plans can differ due to the following:"
Different Costs->
Data volume and statistics
Bind variable types
Initialization parameters - set globally or at session level

Here i dont understand how **Initialization parameters - set globally or at session level** affects execution plan.
can anybody explain this?
Also is there any other way i can check the SQL statements for performance other than explain plan or autotrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GLOBAL OR SESSION parameters**
Oracle is setup with a set of initialisation parameters.  Those will be used by default if nothing is specified to override them. They can be overriden by using an ALTER SESSION (just affects a single user) or ALTER SYSTEM (affects all users until Oracle is restarted) commands to change things at the session or system level or by using optimiser hints in the code. These can have an effect on the plans you see.

In relation to explain plan, a different Oracle database may have different initialisation parameters or have some session/system parameters set which could mean the SAME code behaves differently (by getting a different execution plan on one Oracle database compared to another Oracle database).

Also, as the execution plan is affected by the data chosen, it's possible that a query or package that runs fine in TEST never finishes in PRODUCTION where the volume of data is much larger.  This is a common issue when code is not tested with accurate volumes of data (or at least with the table statistics imported from a production database if test cannot hold a full volume of production like data).

**TRACING**
The suggestions so far tell you how to trace an individual statement assuming you know which statement has a problem but you mention you have a shell script with several SQL statements.

If you are using a here document with a single call to SQL plus containin several SQL statements like this ...

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 sqlplus -S user/pass <<EOF
 set heading off
 BEGIN
      -- DO YOUR FIRST SQL HERE
      -- DO YOUR SECOND SQL HERE
 END;
 /

 EOF
```

... you can create a single oracle trace file like this

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 sqlplus -S user/pass <<EOF
 set heading off
 BEGIN
      ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8'
      -- DO YOUR FIRST SQL HERE
      -- DO YOUR SECOND SQL HERE
 END;
 /

 EOF
```

- Note the level 8 is for tracing with WAITS.  You can do level 4 (bind variables), and level 12 (binds and waits) but i've always found the problem just with level 8.  Level 12 can also take a lot longer to execute and in full size environments.

Now run the shell script to do a single execution, then check where your trace file is created in SQL PLUS using

```
  SQL> show parameter user_dump_dest
  /app/oracle/admin/rms/udump
```

Go to that directory and if no other tracing has been enabled, there will be a .trc file that contains the trace of the entire run of the SQL in your script.

You need to convert this to readable format with the unix tkprof command like this

```
  unix> tkprof your.trc ~/your.prf sys=no sort=fchela,exeela
```

Now change to your home directory and there will be a .prf file with the SQL statements listed in order of those that take the most execution time or fetch time to execute along with the explain plans. This set of parameters to tkprof allow you to focus on fixing the statements that take the longest and therefore have the biggest return for tuning.

Note that if your shell script runs several sqlplus commands, each one will create a separate session and therefore adding an ALTER SESSION statement to each one will create separate trace files.

Also, dont forget that it's easy to get lost in the detail, sometimes tuning is about looking at the overall picture and doing the same thing another way rather than starting by working on a single SQL that may gain a few seconds but in the overall scheme doesnt help to reduce the overall run time.

If you can, try to minimise the number of update statements as if you have one big table, it will be more efficient if you can do the updates in one pass of the table (and have indexes supporting the updates) rather than doing lots of small updates.

Maybe you can post the relevant parts of your script, the overall time it takes to run and the explain plan if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 3):

There are several (initialization) parameters that can influence the execution plan for your statement. The one that immediately comes to mind is [OPTIMIZER_MODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams161.htm#REFRN10145)

Other not so obvious session are things like NLS settings that might influence the usability of indexes.

An alternative approach to get the real execution plan (apart from tracing the session and using tkprof) is to use the `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */` hint together with 'dbms_xplan.display_cursor()'.

This is done by actually running the statement using the above hint first (so this does take longer than a "normal" explain):

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * 
from some_table
  join ...
where ...
```

Then after that statement is finished, you can retrieve the used plan using dbms_xplan:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'ALLSTATS LAST');
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I only trust the rowsource operations because this gives the exact plan as is executed. There do exist a few parameters that have effect on how the plan is constructed. Most parameters will be set on instance level but can be over ridden on session level. This means that every session could have it's own set of effective parameters.

Problem you have is that you need to know the exact settings of the session that is going to run your script. There are a few ways to change session level settings. Settings can be changed in a logon trigger, in a stored procedure or in the script.

If your script is not influenced by a logon trigger and does not call any code that issues `alter session` statements, you will be using the settings that your instance has.